# Help with Ms Access 2007 Combo boxes

Tags: vba, microsoft-access, forms

What's the most efficient way to "chain" combo/boxes in an Access 2007 form, so that the result of the first affected the contents of the second? I already know how to associate a combo box on a form with a query.

Here's a example of my scenario:

**cmbCarMake**

*Behavior: User starts typing, and list shows all manufacturers in a table starting with those characters (e.g., "Ford")*

**cmbCarModel**

*Behavior: Once cmbCarMake has a selected a Make, this object will limit the possible models the user can search for by only displaying models from that one manufacturer. (e.g., "F-150")*

Thank you for any examples/links.

Comment: Have you Googled on "Access cascading combo box"? If not, why not? If you had, you'd have plenty of explanations of the usual solutions to this problem, as it's one of the most common Access questions. Certainly once you've looked at those, you may have questions, and we'll be glad to help, but please, first do your homework!

Comment: Also, have you seen this StackOverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560060/cascading-combo-box-causing-empty-fields-in-next-record